# Disable auto sign in for users right after a registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Devise gem. It's not configured to be `:confirmable`, however I want an user not to log in automatically right after a registration process. For some reason, now they are logged in automatically which exactly the opposite of what I want.

So how do I do that?

Comment: Is there some other step your users need to complete?

Comment: @ZachKemp, an admin should accept them, they don't do anything.

Comment: See this page on the Devise wiki: [How to: Require admin to activate account before sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)

Comment: @ZachKemp which the part is the answer to my question?

Comment: The whole thing, I thought. Does "an admin should accept them" not mean the same thing as "require admin to activate account"?

Comment: @ZachKemp the question is "how do I make users not be auto logged in right after a registration"? I'm not asking about admin's confirmation.

Comment: That page demonstrates how to delay sign in based on an attribute on the users table.

Comment: @ZachKemp which the part is the answer to my question?

Comment: @MariusKavansky if Zach's answer is not exactly, completely 100% what you want, please outline the workflow in an upload of how you want the user flow to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Basically, follow the above steps.  In your after_sign_up_path_for method, you can call

```
sign_out resource
```

then redirect them to whatever page you want them to go to (perhaps root, or the login page).

The user is logged in via the sign_up method called by devise; it's standard procedure -- many websites log in users immediately after they sign up.  Most that don't require confirmation first, so your use case it somewhat atypical.  Still, doing the method I described above should do what you want, without having to implement confirmable or doing any membership approvals.

Answer (score 1):

Signing in the user after sign up is achieved by the `sign_up` method in `Devise::RegistrationsController` that gets called by the `[create][1]` action. You can simply override this method with an empty one to prevent signing in. That worked for me!

In `app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
   end
end
```

Note: replace `users` with your table name.

**Extra:**

If you allow only admins to add new users , or perhaps other admins, and use the create action to add them, this previous method will also give you the benefit of not having to sign out. You can customize what page to be redirected to after signup by overriding the `after_sign_up_path_for` method in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
        '/users/show' # replace with the path you want
    end
```